# Why does ssh drop out when traffic stops?

Tags: connection

I have read many posts on ssh connection refused, but I have this and other ssh issues. Here is my research:

1) occurs on many of my machines, all running Raspian and latest version of sshd

2) when ssh drops out, I immediately get "connection refused" when I try to reconnect

3) nmap shows port 22 is closed when I can no longer connect

4) system gets a dynamic ip address, so presumably no ip address conflicts

5) seems to occur with headless machines, so I can't run any tests on them

6) machine is active, and http access to them remains working

7) machines send me periodic status reports via my script in /etc/cron.hourly. I see that sshd remains running even when I can't connect, and it is listed like this:

root      3487     1  0 Sep06 ?        00:00:31 sshd: root@pts/0

8) an ssh connection stays up if I keep constant traffic, such as from top, but sometimes the connection dies as soon as I close top and return to the command line

9) ssh can stay up for weeks, or sometimes just hours

How can I fix this ???

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Is it a wifi adapter or wired Ethernet?  Have you done 'sudo apt-get update' followed by sudo apt-get upgrade' I suspect you're using a usb wifi dongle with outdated modules.

Comment: They have wired Ethernet connections.

Comment: What system are you sshing from?

Comment: Windows and Linux.